# Dynamically updating plot (Funcanimation) in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter, plot

I am trying to do a dynamically updating plot in Matplotlib Python 3.x using Tkinter.
It starts with displaying a file dialog for the user to select the .csv file.

Here's the example of the .csv file:
[image: sample CSV File]

I want to plot each row then the plot is updated & plotting the next row.

Here's what I currently have:

```
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

xs =[]
ys = []

csvFile = filedialog.askopenfile(mode='r', filetypes=(("CSV file", "*.csv"), ("All files", "*.*")), title="Select a  CSV file")
csvFile2 = pd.read_csv(csvFile, header=[2])

selectedColumn = csvFile2.iloc[0:, 3:]

selectedArray = selectedColumn.to_numpy()  # arrays


def animate():
    for row in selectedArray:
        plt.clf() #clear current figure
        plt.plot(row)
        plt.title('Plot')
        plt.xlabel('Radar No')
        plt.ylabel('Value')

        plt.ylim(0.2, 0.9)  # Keeping the y axis stays the same during the loop
        plt.draw()
        plt.pause(0.0078) #0.0078 if the frequency is 128Hz -- Idk about this one
        plt.show()
animate()
```

It does plot the numbers dynamically, but the fps is so slow, about 5 fps.

Therefore, I am looking for another method, Funcanimation, but I am not sure how to use it.
Inside the variable **Selectedarray** is something like this:

> [0.489377 0.481563 0.477656 ... 0.300366 0.294261 0.288156]
> [0.489866 0.48254  0.478633 ... 0.300855 0.294994 0.288645]
> [0.489377 0.481319 0.478144 ... 0.300122 0.293773 0.288156]

....

I believe using Funcanimation is faster and I could control the speed(?) Could anyone pls help.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using fig.canvas.flush_events()? Something like this:       line.set_ydata(row)    fig.canvas.draw()    fig.canvas.flush_events(next row)    plt.show() ...

Comment: No, I haven't, but I will try it then. Thanks heaps :)

Comment: Oh I think you don't have to input your next row in flush_events. I'll try to write a short general answer below, it's hard without concrete data.

Answer (score 1):

There's a way doing these things with the flush_events() method. I'll try to give a general answer here, may need to adapt a little bit for the specific data and needs. Also, consider using time.sleep() to control for the speed of figure update.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

myarray = pd.read_excel("yourdata.xlsx", index_col=None)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
i=0
for row in myarray.head().itertuples():
    print(row)
    if i == 0:
        line, = ax.plot(row)
    else:
        line.set_ydata(row)
    fig.canvas.draw()
    fig.canvas.flush_events()
    plt.show()
    i += 1
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried to use this on the code, the graph is plotted, but it isn't dynamically changing, that means I still have to modify the code a bit, right?

Comment: I edited the answer based on a simple excel file with numeric data. It works for that sort of data structure. You may need to remove your column names or replace them by integers going from 0 to N columns (maybe, please check).